# Trying to build blender, not sure where to put "configure flags"

Tags: cmake, blender

I've been going through cmake documentation, Blender documentation etc etc.. can't find anything about where these "configure flags" need to go. I can't even find anything on whether it's project specific or just a convention of cmake.

Blender's install_deps.sh told me I need to set the following flags...

```
-D OPENEXR_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/openexr
-D OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/oiio
-D WITH_CYCLES_OSL=ON
-D WITH_LLVM=ON
-D LLVM_VERSION=3.3
-D CYCLES_OSL=/opt/lib/osl
-D WITH_CODEC_FFMPEG=ON
-D FFMPEG_LIBRARIES='avformat;avcodec;avutil;avdevice;swscale;rt;theoradec;theoraenc;theora;vorbisenc;vorbisfile;vorbis;ogg;x264;openjpeg'
-D FFMPEG=/opt/lib/ffmpeg
```

Which is well and good, but how/where do I pass this info along to cmake?

Comment: These are probably meant to be passed as command line args when you run CMake.

Comment: If you do `cmake -DMyVar=Value .` from your build directory, then `MyVar=Value` gets cached to the CMakeCache.txt.  I think this is a better way to put values into the CMakeCache.txt (as opposed to editing the file by hand).

Comment: I found that I can specify what libraries cmake uses using ldconfig, editing the ldconfig config files and setting up proper symlinks. ldconfig can even be used to manage multiple (or compiled vs managed) versions of the same library.

As it turns out, this would be the prefered way to setup a "a build environment", as opposed to supplying command line arguments or manually eding CMakeCache.txt files.

Answer (score 2):

I know of two ways to send the configure information to cmake.

The first way is when calling cmake when first setting up the build.

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DOPENEXR_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/openexr -DWITH_CYCLES_OSL=ON -DWITH_LLVM=ON ../blender
```

Notice no space between `-D` and the variable name. String options can be enclosed in quotes, useful for paths with spaces.

The second way is using the cmake "configuration utility". This is available as a cli command `ccmake ../blender` or as a gui application called cmake-gui. Remember to Configure and Generate after changing options.

Note that some of these options are configured as advanced and are only visible by pressing T in ccmake or ticking Advanced in the gui app.

Comment: +1+1+1+1

This was exactly what was needed.

Aside from this, I found that I could manually configure library locations with ldconfig, their locations, and which ones are used by default by altering the ldconfig config files and using symlinks.